# OpenID Selector in Drupal 7.7 is not working for me

Tags: drupal, openid

I am using Drupal 7.7 and am hoping to use OpenID Selector (7.x-1.x-dev). I installed Javascript OpenID Selector 1.3 as required. I enabled OpenID 7.7 first and then enabled OpenID Selector (7.x-1.x-dev) and OpenID Selector for Drupal login (7.x-1.x-dev).

Now I am able to see a few provider icons. However select one such as Yahoo. I always get this error message:

Sorry, that is not a valid OpenID. Ensure you have spelled your ID correctly

How can I fix this?

Thanks for any help!!!

Answer (score 1):

I got it working finally. I need to uncomment PHP's ssl module.